# includes function Iterate over all array in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a code which iterates over an array of Objects and checks if it contains admin word.If it contains then I want to call Admin API and if not then I want to call Non-Admin API.
The code works fine however the issue is while iterating it say authority contains 5 Objects and 3rd index contains admin keyword then the logic calls 2 non-admin api and 1 admin api and then again 2 non-admin apis.
Is there a better way to write the code that the logic will check whether the whole array contains admin keyword or not and call admin API or Non-Admin API only once.

```
if (tempAuth && tempAuth.length > 0) {
      this.auth = tempAuth.filter(x => {
        if (x.authority.includes('admin')) {
            // Admin API
            this.getalldetails();
          }
         else {
          // Non Admin API
           this.getUserdetails();
         }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the `some` method to check if the auth criteria is ever met. Then you can use that boolean value to determine what to do next.

```js
if (tempAuth && tempAuth.length > 0) {
  this.auth = tempAuth.some(x => x.authority.includes('admin'));
  if (this.auth) {
    this.getalldetails();
  } else {
    this.getUserdetails();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to determine whether at least one element in the array `tempAuth` includes `authority` as admin. If yes, then we set `getalldetails` to `this.auth` else we pass `getUserdetails`

```
if (tempAuth && tempAuth.length > 0) {
   var found = tempAuth.some(x => x.authority.includes('admin'));
   this.auth = found ? this.getalldetails() : this.getUserdetails();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The array function `some` returns a boolean if the condition is true for at least 1 item.

```js
if (tempAuth && tempAuth.length > 0) {
  const isAdmin = tempAuth.some(x => x.authority.includes('admin'));
  if (isAdmin) {
    // Admin API
    this.getalldetails();
  } else {
    // Non Admin API
    this.getUserdetails();
  }
}
```